# Detect SystemUpdate() in an event receiver

Tags: event-receivers

Is it possible to detect whether SystemUpdate() or Update() has been invoked in an event receiver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I've used System.Diagnostics.StackTrace to walk the callstack in order to determine if SystemUpdate() or Update() was called.

Answer (score -1):

if i'm not wrong, the SystemUpdate is invoked under system account. Try to check SPWeb.CurrentUser property.

Comment: If that were true (not sure if it is), we still wouldn't know if the system account invoked `Update()`.